# app.relaunch([options]) is not working in electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I want to change userData path with path defined by user. So, I'm fetching the path from UI, storing it into a file. So that next time app launches, it changes the path.
I wanted to restart the app as soon as user has selected the path. I tried app.relaunch() function. But it didn't work, neither it returned error.

I used exact same example mentioned in documentation. http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/app/#apprelaunchoptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `app.relaunch()` will not actually quit the app, you need to follow it by a call to `app.quit()` or `app.exit()`.

Comment: same here, it just doesn't

Comment: ive tried this in `index.html` and `main.js` and no dice

Answer (score 1):

```
app.relaunch();
app.quit();
```

This code must work, but **Please Note** that while debugging (i.e. in Visual studio code) **after `app.quit()` debugger disconnects** and kills whole application, **therefore app will not restart**. You might want to test it on application that is already installed or run through npm.